# Should I pass the layout's rootview to Snackbar?

Tags: android, android-snackbar

As far as I understand we can put any view, such as child view of our root layout when initializing **Snackbar**.

Quoted from the document:

> Snackbar will try and find a parent view to hold Snackbar's view from the value given to view.

However, this statement makes me think of putting the root view might be the best approach. Since traversing the nodes can be taxing especially a layout with a complex hierarchy.

Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: Each `View` can have only one parent, so going up the hierarchy is trivial. Any savings you might gain from using the root `View` instead would likely be immeasurable.

Comment: @MikeM. I see, thanks for your answer.